# Does the Markov Blanket of a node include the node itself?

Tags: graph-theory, machine-learning

The definition states the [Markov Blanket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_blanket) includes the parents of the children of the node, so does this include the node itself too?

Answer (score 7):

No! The Markov Blanket does not contain the node itself. The point of the Markov Blanket $\partial A$ is that given any other node $B$ in the network, $P(A|\partial A, B) = P(A|\partial A)$. That is, $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $\partial A$, the Markov Blanket of $A$. If the Markov Blanket included $A$ itself, this statement would be a tautology, and lack any content.